# Display data from common topic in Freebase using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, freebase

I am playing around with Freebase and have had some decent success, but have hit a wall. My MQL is below. I do not have any issue displaying name,latin name, etc, which I created in my base. I do not know how to display the article which is in a different base.

Here is the jQuery I am using to display data:

```
  $('<div>',{text:this.name}).appendTo(document.body);
```

Thank you very much,
Todd

```
query : [
  {
    "/common/topic/article": {
      "guid": null,
      "limit": 1,
      "optional": true
    },
    "/common/topic/image": {
      "id": null,
      "limit": 1,
      "optional": true
    },
    "id": null,
    "larval_food": [
      {
        "index": null,
        "lang": "/lang/en",
        "limit": 6,
        "optional": true,
        "sort": "index",
        "type": "/type/text",
        "value": null
      }
    ],
    "latin_name": [
      {
        "index": null,
        "lang": "/lang/en",
        "limit": 6,
        "optional": true,
        "sort": "index",
        "type": "/type/text",
        "value": null
      }
    ],
    "limit": 60,
    "name": null,
    "s0:type": [
      {
        "id": "/base/butterflies/butterfly",
        "link": [
          {
            "timestamp": [
              {
                "optional": true,
                "type": "/type/datetime",
                "value": null
              }
            ],
            "type": "/type/link"
          }
        ],
        "type": "/type/type"
      }
    ],
    "sort": "-s0:type.link.timestamp.value",
    "type": "/base/butterflies/butterfly"
  }
]
```

Comment: If the answer below doesn't answer the question you were asking, can you clarify the question with additional info on what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
  "type": "/base/butterflies/butterfly"
```

to the type of the thing you actually want to include.

As an aside, that looks like a query which was exported from one of the Freebase.com view pages.  It can be greatly simplified and some of the stuff, like the sorting, you probably want removed altogether.

Here's your query simplied (I also recommend using the standard scientific name property instead of inventing your own "Latin name" property):

```
[{
    "type": "/base/butterflies/butterfly",
    "mid": null,
    "name": null,
    "/common/topic/article": [],
    "/common/topic/image": ["mid":null,"optional":true],
    "larval_food": [],
    "latin_name": [],
    "/biology/organism_classification/scientific_name" : [],
  }]
```

Here's a version of the query which shows all organism classifications (species in this case) which have the tribe Danaini two levels up.  It optionally decorates it with data (larval_food) from your base, if it exists:

```
[{
  "type": "/biology/organism_classification",
  "higher_classification": [{
    "/biology/organism_classification/higher_classification": "Danaini"
  }],
  "mid": null,
  "name": null,
  "scientific_name": [],
  "/common/topic/article": [],
  "/common/topic/image": [{
    "mid":      null,
    "optional": true
  }],
  "/base/butterflies/butterfly/larval_food": [],
}]
```

You can try it here: http://tinyurl.com/6wht7lx